# JavaScript in IE11 giving me script error 1003

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I have a site with an accordion and some javascript. In Firefox everything is working as it should, but in IE11 I get the error

> SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

I narrowed it down to this piece of code in my .js file:

```
var nmArray = new Array();

function saveplayers() {
  var x;

  for (x=0;x<32;x++) {
    var y = "i"+eval(x+1);
    nmArray[x]=document.getElementById(y).value;
  }
  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savep.php",
    data: ({ nmArray }),
    cache: false
  });
}
```

The error complains there should be a colon after nmArray in `({ nmAray })`

If I take this function out, my site works again. For debugging I stripped down my HTML, and I'm not even calling this function. I just included the .js file.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick replies. I now understand why it does work in FF and not in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `({nmArray})` in a browser that supports ES6 is a shortcut for `{nmArray: nmArray}`. IE11 doesn't support this feature (based on the error you're receiving), so you'll have to rewrite it as:

```
data: ({ nmArray: nmArray }),
```

See here for an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6

note that in this case you can omit the wrapping `()`

```
data: { nmArray: nmArray },
```

Comment: Sweet IE. Thanks for not following standards **AGAIN**